Bootstrap sampling to get monthly statistic from daily data
I have daily (iid) data for historic winter seasons: $d:$ (price, value, temperature, etc).
The "value" is actually a concave up function of "price" and the other covariates.
I'm interested in seeing the value of a month, so the sum of the "value" for exactly 30 days. All data is iid and each day is equally likely to appear in a month.
My idea is to take 10_000 samples of size 30 from my daily data and compute the statistic, and use that as the distribution. I am using the historic data as the discrete distribution approximation for the actual daily distribution F.
I've read through some of the proofs on bootstrap estimation, and most assume that the bootstrap sample size is equal to your data sample size.  I get that this may be needed for statistics such as moments, but in my case, is using a different sample size like this justified? Where can this go wrong?

How do you know these values are iid? That would be rather surprising for a time series of this kind. Do I understand correctly that you don't have information which day is which (when exactly it happened)? How come? What do you want to do with the resulting bootstrap distribution or how would you want to interpret it?

@ChristianHennig , it's just an assumption .. it is a commodity that depends on the daily wind shape.  The price has a distribution each day, so within a month, majority of observations are low prices with a few high prices when it hits.
re: what i want to do:
historic data is daily. there is a monthly product that is a bundle of 30 daily contracts that I want to use to hedge. I can't hedge each day independently, I can only hedge groups of 30 at a time. So i want a distribution on a month (group of 30 days).

Do these 30 days have to be consecutive? If this is so, I'd for sure try to compare the bootstrap distribution that you get with a distribution for 30 consecutive days, maybe even taken separately for different periods, to see whether there are systematic differences to drawing days as if they were i.i.d. If there are, i.i.d. sampling wouldn't seem such a good idea.

I think a good analaogy is that I am looking at solar production and corresponding prices they see.  Each day there is a similar solar shape (rise in morning, set in evenign), but some days in january are cloudy so there is none. So there are latent proceses driving this distribution .I have historic daily data, so I am thinking of taking the past few years of januaries, and sampling from these set of daily points to create a month . But i'm not sure if this is mathematically valid.  Will definitely try comparing a sample to a sliding window, good idea.
